# Mapping of jersey filter conflicts with another servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jersey, mapping

In web.xml there is such a servlet:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Bla</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Bla</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And I have a jersey filter and an approp. web.xml settings are:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MY API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>BlaResponseFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MY API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The aim is to bind a filter to any responce.

Of course that is not working due to multiple servlets mapping into the same path (/*)

What is another way to do it? I need to run special code at the time when a response is generated already but before sending it to user for any requests.

Comment: What did you tried so far? And whats about **ContainerResponseFilter** and custom **MessageBodyWriter**?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters` int the deployment descriptor should be a class that implements `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter` interface and which must override the `filter` method.

So the provide value seems to be not a legal one. Create you own filter:

```java
package some.package.filter;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

public class BlaResponseFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {  
 @Override
 public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    // you custom operations
  return request;
 }
}
```

Then regiter it:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MY_API</servlet-name><!-- Avoid space characters -->
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>some.package.filter.BlaResponseFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MY_API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```